# monkeypatch in python, leaking mocks to other tests causing them to fail

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, monkeypatching

I am monkeypatching the other function calls while writing pytest unittests as below:

```
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch
from third_party import ThirdParty

def test_my_func():
    resp1= "resp1"
    monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()
    def mock_other_method(*args, **kwargs):
        return resp1
    monkeypatch.setattr(ThirdParty, "other_method", mock_other_method)
    assert ThirdParty().other_method() == "resp1"
    # Some assertions

def test_my_func2():
    monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()
    expected_result = "This is expected"
    result_third_party = ThirdParty().other_method()
    assert result_third_party == expected_result
```

where,
third_party.py has:

```
class ThirdParty:
       def other_method(self):
          return "This is expected"
```

These tests when ran independently run fine (I just wrote it, so there might be some syntax error). But when I run it as **pytest -v**, 2nd test will fail. The reason is that on calling other_method, it will return the mocked method: mock_other_method, and since the response is different it will fail. Please suggest some solution to this

Comment: This works for me after fixing the code (missing `monkeypatch` argument, missing `self`). Can you post a really reproducable example?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, sorry about that, I have updated the proper working code. The problem is that these tests work fine when run independently. But, pytest -v fails for the second test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`monkeypatch` is a [pytest fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html) and as such
not supposed to be imported. Instead, you have to provide it as an argument in the test functions. Pytest loads all fixtures at test start and looks them up by name, so the correct usage would be:

```py
from third_party import ThirdParty
# no import from pytest internal module! 

def test_my_func(monkeypatch):
    resp1 = "resp1"
    def mock_other_method(*args, **kwargs):
        return resp1
    monkeypatch.setattr(ThirdParty, "other_method", mock_other_method)
    assert ThirdParty().other_method() == resp1
```

The `monkeypatch` fixture has function scope, meaning that the patching will be reverted after each test function automatically.

Note that using the internal `pytest` API (e.g. importing  `_pytest`) is discouraged, both because it may change with a new version, and because there are more convenient and secure methods to use the features (and not last because these are documented). You should never bother about fixture cleanup yourself, if you use a fixture provided by `pytest` or a `pytest` plugin - it would be too easy to forget the cleanup and get unwanted side effects.

Comment: This makes more sense, hence accepting it. In case someone is using the way I was using, it can be used by monkeypatch.undo()

Comment: For anyone else who lands on this, you can also use it within a context like `with pytest.MonkeyPatch.context() as mp: ...` This will undo your patches once you leave the `with` block.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by adding monkeypatch.undo() at the end of every test. This will prevent the monkeypatch() from leaking into other functions